# Web service error in jquery while using Internet Explorer 10

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have following jQuery ajax code, which calls ASP.NET webservice to save data in database.

```
function SaveDataToParty() {
            var mode = "Save";
            var srno = 0;
            var partyname = $("#p1").val();
            var partyemail = $("#p2").val();
            var partyphone = $("#p3").val();
            var partyaddress = $("#p4").val();
            var webMethod = "../Service/DatabaseHandling.asmx/SaveDataToParty";
            var parameters = "{mode:'" + mode + "',srno:'" + srno + "',partyname:'" + partyname + "',partyemail:'" + partyemail + "',partyphone:'" + partyphone + "',partyaddress:'" + partyaddress + "'}";
            alert(parameters);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: webMethod,
                async:false,
                data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
```

This call following webservice method in asp.net

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function SaveDataToParty(mode As String, srno As String, partyname As String, partyemail As String, partyphone As String, partyaddress As String) As Boolean
    'this will start connection and set transaction to it
    Dim cnstr As String = String.Empty
    cnstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DPMTConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(cnstr)
    Dim tran As SqlTransaction
    cn.Open()
    tran = cn.BeginTransaction
    Try
        'this will handle sp coding
        Dim dcmd As New SqlCommand
        dcmd.Connection = cn
        dcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        'sp execution for party entry
        If mode = "Save" Then
            dcmd.Parameters.Add("@mode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "ADD"
            dcmd.Parameters.Add("@srno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0
        End If
        If mode = "Update" Then
            dcmd.Parameters.Add("@mode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "UPDATE"
            dcmd.Parameters.Add("@srno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = srno
        End If

        dcmd.Parameters.Add("@partyname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = partyname
        dcmd.Parameters.Add("@partyemail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = partyemail
        dcmd.Parameters.Add("@partyphone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = partyphone
        dcmd.Parameters.Add("@partyaddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500).Value = partyaddress

        dcmd.CommandText = "sp_add_update_delete_party"
        dcmd.Transaction = tran
        dcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        tran.Commit()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    Finally
        cn.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

The error is generated in Internet Explorer 10 only.
Error is "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027mode\u0027"

It works fine in Google Chrome.

Any solution?

**EDIT 1**

I have updated this with JSON.stringify and async:false, but still no success with IE10.

**EDIT 2**

In IE10 Developer tools, in network tab, following information is displayed.

```
Key Value
Request POST /hemal/ASPNET/DPMT/Service/DatabaseHandling.asmx/SaveDataToParty HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost/hemal/ASPNET/DPMT/ADMIN/Purchase_Add.aspx
Accept-Language en-IN,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,gu;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host    localhost
Content-Length  0
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=mhp35fbfn3vzoalqvdild5hb; loginstatus=ok
```

I am shocked why content-length is 0. It means that nothing is sent.

Comment: you can get the post Data from IE. using fiddler or something..If you post that data here..we will get a better overview

Comment: @AthulKSurendran, I have updated my code with EDIT 2. Please see

Comment: I don't think you are using stringify correctly?  You should stringify an object.  See my answer.

Comment: I think its a bug in IE10, i solved it with adding following in <head>  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it; however, one thing that seems suspicious to me is that you are stringifying your own json, i.e.,

```
var parameters = "{mode:'" + mode + "',srno:'" + srno + "',partyname:'" + partyname + "',partyemail:'" + partyemail + "',partyphone:'" + partyphone + "',partyaddress:'" + partyaddress + "'}";
```

There is a difference between your implementation and the JSON2.js implementation.  You could write:

```
JSON.stringify({
            mode: mode,
            srno: srno,
            partyname: partyname,
            partyemail: partyemail,
            partyaddress: partyaddress
        }));
```

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/DwTge/9/

Note the difference in the quoting of the param names?

Comment: Main problem with IE10 is, in request headers, nothing is sent, content length is 0. In other browsers, request header is filled with content to be sent. See my EDIT 2 section

Comment: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >, this worked for me. Its a bug in IE10